# How to move from LDAP to RDF

Tags: rdf

I'm looking for a solution to expose or dump LDAP content in RDF.

SquirrelRDF use to be the open source solution. However it moved to Jena, but is not available anymore. Is there anything else out there for the matter?

Comment: What does LDAP have to do with RDF? They're completely different things.

Comment: it means importing directory information into rdf

Comment: Did you every check at squerril ?